# Permission denied when writing a file with Java

Tags: java, lda

I am trying to run the `JGibbLDA` code, and when I run the code using `java -mx512M -cp bin:lib/args4j-2.0.6.jar jgibblda.LDA -est -alpha 0.5 -beta 0.1 -ntopics 100 -niters 1000 -savestep 100 -twords 20 -dfile /path/to/data/data.txt`, I got an error messages:

```
Error while writing word map /wordmap.txt (Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /wordmap.txt (Permission denied),
```

which refers to the following code:

```
public boolean writeWordMap(String wordMapFile){
    try{
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(wordMapFile), "UTF-8"));

        //write number of words
        writer.write(word2id.size() + "\n");

        //write word to id
        Iterator<String> it = word2id.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            String key = it.next();
            Integer value = word2id.get(key);

            writer.write(key + " " + value + "\n");
        }

        writer.close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error while writing word map " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }


}
}
```

I am not familiar with Java but I need to run this piece of code. Could you please tell me what is the wrong with the code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks like the file permissions for `wordmap.txt` just need to be changed.

Comment: As far as I can tell, nothing is wrong with the code. The problem is that the account you're using does not have write permission in, what seems to be, the root directory (`/`).

Comment: You get an exception while writing the file to the file system root directory. The referenced code is for reading the file and does not match the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JGibbLDA site](http://jgibblda.sourceforge.net/) ...

> JGibbLDA also saves a file called wordmap.txt that contains the maps between words and word's IDs (integer).

wordmap.txt is referenced in two files in the source code:

> **LDACmdOption.java** and **Model.java**

The specific errors you mention do not relate to the reading of the wordmap.txt but most likely originate from Dictionary.java AND Estimator.java:

> src/jgibblda/Dictionary.java:   public boolean **writeWordMap(String wordMapFile)**
>
> src/jgibblda/Estimator.java:                    **trnModel.data.localDict.writeWordMap(option.dir + File.separator + option.wordMapFileName);**

More specifically it is using the root directory / and attempting to write to wordmap.txt to the root context. That won't work if you're a non-privileged user and NOT able to write to /. You could try to run the program as root but I DO NOT recommend that as it's an awful idea to break security. What I would recommend is setting:

> option.dir

to a location you are able to write to and try running it again...

From the manual on the site:

> -dir : The input training data directory

So add that to your option list and try again. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `JGibbLDA` uses a `'wordmap.txt'` temp file, and if you don't provide the location of the file then it will try to create one.

Since the `user` you are using to run the `program` does not have the permission to create a new file `'/wordmap.txt'`, hence the error.

To resolve either get the permission to the user (or) provide the location via `-dir /<path>/wordmap.txt` option.